# TypeScript compiler struggling with new Map()

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I am trying to use TypeScript `Map` data structure, but I get the folowing compiler error:

`argument of type '(string | number)'[][] is not assignable to parameter of type 'iterable<[{},{}]>`

My map:

```
 export const PostTypeMap = new Map([
    [0, 'Link'],
    [1, 'Status'],
    [2, 'Photo'],
    [3, 'Video'],
    [4, 'Offer'],
    [5, 'Unknown'],
    [6, 'Event']
]);
```

And my `tsconfig.js`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports":true
  },
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "resolveGlobs": true,
    "forkChecker": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false
}
```

Comment: Is `PostTypeMap` declared anywhere else? Even in another file? I've just pasted your code into [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) and it compiled fine.

Comment: It's not but it's not a problem with name collision. Even if I name it `dummyMap` it still shows the same error.

Comment: Change your `"target": "ES5",` to `"target": "ES6",`. Any difference now? I believe that `Map` was introduced in `ES6`, thus TypeScript is having trouble inferring the type of `PostTypeMap`. Looks like it thinks it's a `Tuple`??

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to signify that there will only ever be **two** items in the nested arrays, not just any number of items:

```
export const PostTypeMap = <[number, string][]> new Map([
    [0, 'Link'],
    [1, 'Status'],
    [2, 'Photo'],
    [3, 'Video'],
    [4, 'Offer'],
    [5, 'Unknown'],
    [6, 'Event']
]);
```